# Bulk editing custom attribute in Exchange online with Powershell (Script not working as intended)

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, office365

Looking to get some help with my powershell script. Basically have a script that I use to bulk edit fields in Azure AD for multiple users and it works fine. I tried to use it for editing custom attributes for multiple users via Exchange Online and it is not working. I'm guessing it does not work the same for EO. The goal here is to pull a csv that has 2 columns (the users emails address "userprincipalname", and one column for the value I want to add for "customattribute1") Any help is appreciated.

```
# Connect to ExchangeOnline
Connect-ExchangeOnline

# Get CSV content
$CSVrecords = Import-Csv C:\pathtofile.csv

# Create arrays for skipped and failed users
$SkippedUsers = @()
$FailedUsers = @()

# Loop trough CSV records
foreach ($CSVrecord in $CSVrecords) {
    $upn = $CSVrecord.UserPrincipalName
    $user = Get-Mailbox -Filter "userPrincipalName eq '$upn'"  
    if ($user) {
        try{
        $user | Set-Mailbox -customattribute1 $CSVrecord.customattribute1 
        } catch {
        $FailedUsers += $upn
        Write-Warning "$upn user found, but FAILED to update."
        }
    }
    else {
        Write-Warning "$upn not found, skipped"
        $SkippedUsers += $upn
    }
}
```

Comment: What is in `$CSVrecord.customattribute1` ? What is the error message? Also passing the UPN through the pipeline to this cmdlet doesn't make any sense in your example. `Set-Mailbox -Identity $upn -CustomAttribute1 <string>` is clean coding.

Comment: The code as it is should work so it basically depends on what your data is. 
"it is not working" is not providing enough info to provide an answer. Also, if the userprincipalname in your CSV is an email address, you can use it as a paramenter in the get-mailbox cmdlet. filtering here is superfluous as you expect just one result and the userprincipalname is known.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there could be 2 points that leads fail to set `customattribute1`.

1. The filter expression should be :  `"userPrincipalName -eq '$upn'"`
2. Seems I can't find the `-Delimiter` param while you import your .CSV file which will lead to unbale to pull column value correctly.

Try the code below that works perfectly for me:

```
Connect-ExchangeOnline

$SkippedUsers = @()
$FailedUsers = @()

$CSVrecords = Import-Csv "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test.csv" -Delimiter ","
foreach($CSVrecord in $CSVrecords ){
    $upn = $CSVrecord.UserPrincipalName
    $user = Get-Mailbox -Filter "userPrincipalName -eq '$upn'"  
    if ($user) {
        try{
        $user | Set-Mailbox -customattribute1 $CSVrecord.customattribute1 
        } catch {
        $FailedUsers += $upn
        Write-Warning "$upn user found, but FAILED to update."
        }
    }
    else {
        Write-Warning "$upn not found, skipped"
        $SkippedUsers += $upn
    }
}
```

My test .csv file:

[image]

After run the PS command, try to get `customattribute1` of my test user:
[image]

Let me know if you have more questions.

Comment: This worked exactly as needed! I see the errors in my script now. I was able to confirm the needed changes were made running $user.CustomAttricute1 in an ExchangeOnline connected powershell session, as well as through the Exchange online portal. Thank you!